# How To integrate linkedin with a asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, linkedin-api

How To integrate linkedin with a asp.net application. I mean how to send data from linkedin to my custom app and from my custom app to linkedin.

Answer (score 0):

I have found some links for you.May be helped to you.Please check that. :)

[Linkedin with Asp.net](http://www.geekbit.es/2013/03/integrate-linked-in-javascript-api-with.html)

[LinkedIn API Integration in ASP.Net](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/LinkedIn-API-Integration-in-ASPNet.aspx)